# Test Percentage Calculator

Tags: c#, testing, textbox

I am making a program in which users enter their own flash cards in and then can answer them inside a textbox. I want to be able to test the answer to see if they have got the answer they put right or not. So my idea is that they will have a question above such as 'What do sheep look like?' and then they will write the answer in a textbox 'White and Fluffy' and then when they click reveal it will show them both the full correct answer 'White, Cute and Fluffy' and then workout how many marks they got for it. So i need help with working out a way to show if they got the answer right or wrong, e.g. 2/3 marks?

Thanks

UPDATE

I want a method of marking for my program, that is my question

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Are you looking for a control to put on the user interface to display their marks for them? What do you currently have? Are you using Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: Or is your question about a method to work out the score for each answer?

Answer (score 1):

look at this :
[Levenshtein Distance algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344320/comparing-strings-with-tolerance/2344347#2344347)