# How much two strings are similar?(90%,100%,40%)

Tags: algorithm

I have an input string and a collection of strings and I want to compare the input string and find the best choices to view.I want to write a function that tell me how much this two string are similar.have you any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing strings with tolerance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344320/comparing-strings-with-tolerance)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For 'short' string differences the algorithm you are searching for is called:

**Levenshtein distance**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

For seeking differences in sentences you may wish to check for algorithms that solve the '[longest common sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)' problem.

One tool that does that is the (originally unix) '[diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)'

Comment: Thanks so much.Is there any algorithm to compare two sentences?

Answer (score 1):

Well, Perl has a String::Approx function which seems that does the job for you. But in general, you might want to take a look at:  [Levenshtein Distance algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Some other good resources are (Mostly explained in C#):

[Comparing strings with tolerance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2344320/337294)
http://mihkeltt.blogspot.com/2009/04/dameraulevenshtein-distance.html
[http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Levenshtein%20distance%3A%20calculating%20similarity%20of%20strings](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Levenshtein%20distance:%20calculating%20similarity%20of%20strings)
http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein