# Find Strings with certain Hamming distance LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, string-matching, hamming-distance

If we run the following (*thanks to @octavioccl for help*) LINQ Query:

```
var result = stringsList
.GroupBy(s => s)
  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)        
  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
  .Select(g => g.Key);
```

It gives us all the strings which occur in the list atleast twice (*but exactly matched i.e. Hamming Distance =0*).

I was just wondering if there is an elegant solution (***all solutions I have tried so far either use loops and a counter which is ugly or regex***) possible where we can specify the hamming distance in the `Where` clause to get those strings as well which lie within the specified Hamming Distance range?

**P.S: All the strings are of equal length**

**UPDATE**

Really thanks to krontogiannis for his detailed answer. As I mentioned earlier, I want to get list of strings with hamming distance below the given threshold. His code is working perfectly fine for it (*Thanks again*).

Only thing remaining is to take the strings out of the 'resultset' and insert/add into a `List'

Basically this is what I want:

```
List<string> outputList = new List<string>();
foreach (string str in patternsList)
            {
                var rs = wordsList
    .GroupBy(w => hamming(w, str))
    .Where(h => h.Key <= hammingThreshold)
    .OrderByDescending(h => h.Key)
    .Select(h => h.Count());
outputList.Add(rs); //I know it won't work but just to show what is needed
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: Hamming distance is applicable to strings of equal length. Are all the strings of equal length?

Comment: If you have strings A, B and C, and A is 1 away from B and B is 1 away from C, but A is more than 1 away from C, how do you want to group these? ie. if they were numbers and you want to group all numbers that are maximum 1 away, and you have numbers 1, 2, and 3, what group(s) would you like to create from this?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Good point Lasse. Kronto handled it pretty well in his answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calculating the hamming distance between two strings using LINQ can be done in an elegant way:

```
Func<string, string, int> hamming = (s1, s2) => s1.Zip(s2, (l, r) => l - r == 0 ? 0 : 1).Sum();
```

You question is a bit vague about the 'grouping'. As you can see to calculate the hamming distance you need two strings. So you either need to calculate the hamming distance for all the words in your string list vs an input, or calculate the distance between all for the words in your list (or something different that you need to tell us :-) ).

In any way i'll give two examples for input

```
var words = new[] {
    "hello",
    "rellp",
    "holla",
    "fooba",
    "hempd"
};
```

**Case 1**

```
var input = "hello";
var hammingThreshold = 3;

var rs = words
    .GroupBy(w => hamming(w, input))
    .Where(h => h.Key <= hammingThreshold)
    .OrderByDescending(h => h.Key);
```

**Output** would be something like

```
hempd with distance 3
rellp holla with distance 2
hello with distance 0
```

**Case 2**

```
var hs = words
    .SelectMany((w1, i) => 
        words
            .Where((w2, j) => i > j)
            .Select(w2 => new { Word1 = w1, Word2 = w2 })) // all word pairs except with self
    .GroupBy(pair => hamming(pair.Word1, pair.Word2))
    .Where(g => g.Key <= hammingThreshold)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key);
```

**Output** would be something like

```
(holla, rellp) (fooba, holla) (hempd, hello) with distance 3
(rellp, hello) (holla, hello) with distance 2
```

---

**Edit** To get only the words from the first grouping you can use `SelectMany`

```
var output = rs.SelectMany(g => g).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Huge effort!! Really thankful

Comment: I am having some difficulty in `Select` for case 1. I want to select only strings.

Comment: You can iterate them per group like I do [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ocAfbj). Or you should update your answer to give a bit more info about what is that you are trying to do.

Comment: @TalhaIrfan I've edited my answer to use the 1st case and extract only the words; probably you don't need a grouping after all.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! You really helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

OP asked for Hamming distance, my algorithm uses Levenshtein distance algorithm. But the code is easily transformable.

```cs
namespace Program
{
    public static class Utils
    {
        public static string LongestCommonSubstring(this IEnumerable<string> arr)
        {
            // Determine size of the array
            var n = arr.Count();

            // Take first word from array as reference
            var s = arr.ElementAt(0);
            var len = s.Length;

            var res = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
            {
                for (var j = i + 1; j <= len; j++)
                {
                    // generating all possible substrings
                    // of our reference string arr[0] i.e s
                    var stem = s.Substring(i, j - i);
                    var k = 1;
                    //for (k = 1; k < n; k++) {
                    foreach (var item in arr.Skip(1))
                    {
                        // Check if the generated stem is
                        // common to all words
                        if (!item.Contains(stem))
                            break;

                        ++k;
                    }

                    // If current substring is present in
                    // all strings and its length is greater
                    // than current result
                    if (k == n && res.Length < stem.Length)
                        res = stem;
                }
            }

            return res;
        }

        public static HashSet<string> GetShortestGroupedString(this HashSet<string> items, int distanceThreshold = 3, int minimumStringLength = 2)
        {
            var cluster = new Dictionary<int, List<Tuple<string, string>>>();
            var clusterGroups = new HashSet<string>();

            var itemCount = items.Count * items.Count;
            int k = 0;

            var first = items.First();
            var added = "";
            foreach (var item in items)
            //Parallel.ForEach(merged, item => // TODO
            {
                var computed2 = new List<string>();
                foreach (var item2 in items)
                {
                    var distance = LevenshteinDistance.Compute(item, item2);
                    var firstDistance = LevenshteinDistance.Compute(first, item2);

                    if (!cluster.ContainsKey(distance)) // TODO: check false
                        cluster.Add(distance, new List<Tuple<string, string>>());

                    if (distance > distanceThreshold)
                    {
                        ++k;
                        continue;
                    }

                    cluster[distance].Add(new Tuple<string, string>(item, item2));

                    if (firstDistance > distance)
                    {
                        var computed = new List<string>();
                        foreach (var kv in cluster)
                        {
                            if (kv.Value.Count == 0) continue;
                            var longest = kv.Value.Select(dd => dd.Item1).LongestCommonSubstring();
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(longest)) continue;

                            computed.Add(longest);
                        }

                        var currentAdded = computed.OrderBy(s => s.Length).FirstOrDefault();
                        var diff = string.IsNullOrEmpty(added) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentAdded)
                            ? string.Empty
                            : currentAdded.Replace(added, string.Empty);

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentAdded) && diff.Length == currentAdded.Length)
                        {
                            var ff = computed2.OrderBy(s => s.Length).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (ff.Length >= minimumStringLength)
                                clusterGroups.Add(ff);

                            computed2.Clear(); // TODO: check false
                            computed2.Add(diff);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (diff.Length == 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(added) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentAdded))
                                computed2.Add(diff);
                        }

                        added = currentAdded;
                        cluster.Clear();
                        first = item;
                    }

                    ++k;
                }

                var f = computed2.OrderBy(s => s.Length).FirstOrDefault();
                if (f.Length >= minimumStringLength)
                    clusterGroups.Add(f);
            }
            //});

            return clusterGroups;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains approximate string matching
    /// </summary>
    internal static class LevenshteinDistance
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Compute the distance between two strings.
        /// </summary>
        public static int Compute(string s, string t)
        {
            var n = s.Length;
            var m = t.Length;
            var d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];

            // Step 1
            if (n == 0)
            {
                return m;
            }

            if (m == 0)
            {
                return n;
            }

            // Step 2
            for (var i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)
            {
            }

            for (var j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++)
            {
            }

            // Step 3
            for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                //Step 4
                for (var j = 1; j <= m; j++)
                {
                    // Step 5
                    var cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

                    // Step 6
                    d[i, j] = Math.Min(
                        Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
                        d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
                }
            }
            // Step 7
            return d[n, m];
        }
    }
}
```

The code has two references:

- The LevenshteinDistance class was extracted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2344347/3286975
- The LongestCommonString method was extracted from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-common-substring-array-strings/

My code is being reviewed at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272379/get-shortest-grouped-distinct-string-from-hashset-of-strings so I expect improvements on it.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
int hammingDistance = 2;
var result = stringsList
.GroupBy(s => s.Substring(0, s.Length - hammingDistance))
.Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
.OrderbyDescending(g => g.Count())
.Select(g => g.Key);
```